# SonarQube - filter out info bug

Tags: sonarqube

is there a way to retrieve, using WEB-API, how many 'BUGS' I have from each severity?
blocker_violations,critical_violations,major_violation... return all issues, not only bugs.

if not, what is the best way to disable entire 'info' rules?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of [Quality profile](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles) do you use?

Comment: Hi, the profile inherits from FindBugs + FB-Contrib (java profile that the project customised). Thanks :)